# Reading form a resource file causes a NullPointerExpection

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I tried to execute a Java application by reading from a source file (info.properites) but I get a `NullpointerExeption`. I don't understand the problem.

```Java
package Org.exemple.demo;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        Properties pro = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/info.properties");
            pro.load(input);
        }finally{
            if (input != null){
                input.close();
        }}
        System.out.println( "Application version : " + pro.getProperty("Org.exemple.demo.version" , "?"));
    }
}
```

```
info.proerties
Org.exemple.demo.version = 1.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where is this `info.properties` located?

Comment: Hi Mark,The location of info.proprities is : F:\Maven\mon-appli\src\main\recources\info.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `info.properties` file is available in class path and use this.

```
input=  App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("info.properties");
```

Comment: @LamriTarek  mark it an answer. If it solve your problem. :)